# Cross tab report in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, pivot

My table looks like this

```
Year  S.Person Orange Mango 
2001   BOB       10    12    
2001   JOY       1     25    
2001   KENT      2      5     
2002   BOB       6      3     
2002   JOY       4      7     
2002   KENT      5      4
```

MY requirement is to produce output like this:

```
Year   BOB-Orange BOB-MANGO  JOY-ORANGE JOY-MANGO KENT-ORANGE KENT-MANGO
2001    10         12         1          25        2           5
2002    6           3          4         7         5           4
```

Note S.Person is DYNAMIC & ORANGE,MANGO ARE FIXED

Comment: [What have **YOU** tried so far?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to do this dynamically, try this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

WITH Unpivoted
AS
(
  SELECT 
  Year, 
  SPerson + '-' + ITem AS SPersonItem, 
  value
  FROM
  (
    SELECT * FROM Table1
  ) AS t
  UNPIVOT 
  (
    Value FOR ITem IN(Orange, Mango)
  ) AS u
)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(SPersonItem)
                      FROM Unpivoted
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query = 
  'WITH Unpivoted 
   AS  
   ( 
      SELECT 
        Year, 
        SPerson + ''-'' + ITem AS SPersonItem, 
        value 
      FROM ( SELECT * FROM Table1  ) AS t 
      UNPIVOT 
      ( 
        Value FOR ITem IN( Orange, Mango) 
       ) AS u  
    ) 
    SELECT *  FROM Unpivoted AS u 
    PIVOT 
    ( 
      SUM(value) 
      FOR SPersonItem IN ( ' + @cols + ' ) 
     ) AS p ';

 execute(@query);
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/21cf2/13)

This will give you:

```
| YEAR | BOB-MANGO | BOB-ORANGE | JOY-MANGO | JOY-ORANGE | KENT-MANGO | KENT-ORANGE |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2001 |        12 |         10 |        25 |          1 |          5 |           2 |
| 2002 |         3 |          6 |         7 |          4 |          4 |           5 |
```